# http repository dependency in package-lock.json

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I noticed that when installing packages in ubuntu the package-lock.json generated contains a minority of dependency packages pointing to http://registry.npmjs.org rather than to https://registry.npmjs.org, while majority of them point towards https://registry.npmjs.org.

Should I be concerned over those pointing to http rather than https? should I manually change them to https?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a while the NPM registry itself had a bug where the [tarball reference for various packages included `http` references rather than `https`](https://npm.community/t/some-packages-have-dist-tarball-as-http-and-not-https/285). Once in your cache these versions will continue to be listed with `http` sources.

Within a given project / repository running the following resolved the issue for me:

```
 npm cache clean --force
 rm -rf node_modules/
 git checkout package-lock.json // To undo any https -> http lines if required
 npm install
```